# Group and sum values within the while loop in php

Tags: php

I have a query that returns a list of rows from mysql database, the list of rows generated have of  rows values being the same.

```
Table
id    mAmount   paidAmount
1       100     50
1       100     30
2       200     20
2       200     150
```

I actually want to sum the `paidAmount` and subtract from just one  of  `mAmount` value per the same `id`.

For instance

```
 1 |  (100) - (50 + 0)  = 50    |
 1 |  (100) - (30 + 50) = 20    |
 2 |  (200) - (20 + 0)  = 180   |
 2 |  (200) - (150 + 20) = 30   |
```

I do not want anyone any to give me the entire codes to this, but an idea as to how to go about it using either php with while loop or possibly foreach statements. Thanks really appreciate.

Comment: Here's a nice tutorial on `SUM()` http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-sum/ - Come back when you've tried something and had trouble with something.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I can actually use SUM() to do this in a sql query but the problem is, I want to do this using php while statement.

Comment: @Fred-ii- don't you mean ... *"tried SUMthing"*?

Comment: @charlietfl *hehe*, nice play on words ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Just have to loop and accumulate the paid amount, then do the subtraction.
For this example I suppose you pre-order your records by id and pass the records to an multidimensional array called rows:

```
$currentId = $rows[0]['id'];
$accumulated = 0;
foreach ( $rows as $row ) {
  if ( $row['id'] != $currentId ) {
    $accumulated = 0;
    $currentId = $row['id'];
  } // end if not current id

  $accumulated += $row['paidAmount'];
  $balance = $row['mAmount'] - $accumulated;
  $row['balance'] = $balance;
  $result[] = $row;
} // end foreach

print_r ( $result );
```

Results are printed like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [mAmount] => 100
            [paidAmount] => 50
            [balance] => 50
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [mAmount] => 100
            [paidAmount] => 30
            [balance] => 20
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [mAmount] => 200
            [paidAmount] => 20
            [balance] => 180
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [mAmount] => 200
            [paidAmount] => 150
            [balance] => 30
        )
    )
```